# Corda enterprise license

Tags: corda

I can't find a copy of the Corda enterprise license terms. I wonder why they make it so difficult to find them. Are the terms similar to Red Hat Enterprise Linux?? Anyone knows? Would you be interested to contribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please reach out to sales@r3.com to find more information about Corda Enterprise evaluation program.

More information at https://www.r3.com/download-corda-enterprise/